# Using a collection's aggregation pipeline with all records of another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have two collections:

`Books`

```
{
  "BOOK_ID": "100",
  "BOOK_NAME": "Book 1",
  "BOOK_DESC": "abcd",  
},
{
  "BOOK_ID": "101",
  "BOOK_NAME": "Book 2",
  "BOOK_DESC": "efgh",  
},
{
  "BOOK_ID": "102",
  "BOOK_NAME": "Book 3",
  "BOOK_DESC": "ijkl",  
}
```

`BookGroup`

```
{
  "GROUP_ID": "100",
  "GROUP_NAME": "G1",
  "GROUPS": [
    {
      "BOOK_ID": "100",
      "BOOK_NAME": "Book 1"
    },
    {
      "BOOK_ID": "101",
      "BOOK_NAME": "Book 2"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "GROUP_ID": "101",
  "GROUP_NAME": "G2",
  "GROUPS": [
    {
      "BOOK_ID": "101",
      "BOOK_NAME": "Book 2"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "GROUP_ID": "102",
  "GROUP_NAME": "G3",
  "GROUPS": [
    {
      "BOOK_ID": "100",
      "BOOK_NAME": "Book 1"
    },
    {
      "BOOK_ID": "102",
      "BOOK_NAME": "Book 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a query to get the associated groups of a single book, following is the query:

```
db.BookGroup.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$GROUPS"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "GROUPS.BOOK_NAME": "Book 2"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "group_name": {
        "$push": "$GROUP_NAME"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": false,
      "group_name": true
    }
  }
])
```

It is able to get the group names of a single book `Book 2`. And following is the output:

```
[
  {
    "group_name": [
      "G1",
      "G2"
    ]
  }
]
```

It is working as expected. Now I would like to get the groups associated to each book but I am not able to do it using the pipeline.

Following is the expected output:

```
{
  "BOOK_ID": "100",
  "BOOK_NAME": "Book 1",
  "BOOK_DESC": "abcd",
  "group_name": ["G1", "G3"]
},
{
  "BOOK_ID": "101",
  "BOOK_NAME": "Book 2",
  "BOOK_DESC": "efgh",
  "group_name": ["G1", "G2"]
},
{
  "BOOK_ID": "102",
  "BOOK_NAME": "Book 3",
  "BOOK_DESC": "ijkl",
  "group_name": ["G3"]
}
```

This is the mongo playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SY917FusLhV).

Kindly advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with `$lookup` to join both Books and BookGroup collections and get the `GROUP_NAME`.

```
db.Books.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "BookGroup",
      localField: "BOOK_ID",
      foreignField: "GROUPS.BOOK_ID",
      as: "groups"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      group_name: {
        $map: {
          input: "$groups",
          in: "$$this.GROUP_NAME"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "groups"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cDR061rdXtE)

Comment: worked like a charm. Thank you for youyr kind help.